# Google Script not splitting array at comma

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var String = "One,Three,Eight";

var temp = String.split(",");

var test = (temp[1][0]);

Browser.msgBox(''+test+'', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
```

I've searched high and wide for why this won't return:

"One" as (temp[0][0])

"Three" as (temp[1][0])

"Eight" as (temp[2][0])

They are only returning O, T and E respectively in the message box.
I want each word to be its own array index, is it something to do with a limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the code by using `Logger.log()`.

```
function sandbox() {
  var String = "One,Three,Eight";
  var temp = String.split(",");
  Logger.log(temp);
}
```

This will show you the following value for `temp`: [One, Three, Eight]

If you log the elements of the array:

`temp[0]` = 'One'

`temp[1]` = 'Three'

`temp[2]` = 'Eight'

If you use `temp[1][0]` you get the first letter from 'Three'.

#### Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Accessing array elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#accessing_array_elements)
- [String: Character Access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#character_access)

Comment: Ah right thanks a lot, i have gotten so used to using [x][x] from getValues in assorted arrays I didn’t know split only used one [x] for a similar result

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer as solved.